# how cross column correlation is handled by PostgreSQL Optimizer

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

There is often a relationship or **correlation between the data stored** in different **columns** of the same table. For example, in the customers table, the values in the c_state column are influenced by the values in the country_id column, as the state of XYZ is only going to be found in the country ABC.

I think PostgreSQL assumes predicates are **mutually independent** and selectivities for each predicate on the same relation are **multiplied** together. Hence selectivity estimates will be much smaller than actuals and **non-optimal** access paths may be chosen when data is highly dependent and skewed. How to avoid this in PostgreSQL?

Can we create some kind of **multi-column statistics** on a group of columns in PostgreSQL 9.3.5. Is there any support for **Multi-dimensional histograms**?

Answer (score 7):

You're correct, Pg assumes independence, and this can be a problem when there's a correlation. The analyser doesn't know how to find correlations and the optimiser doesn't know how to use any such information even if the analyser could find it. There's no support for multi-dimensional histograms or storing cross-column correlation information.

There have been *many* discussions about this on the pgsql-hackers and pgsql-general lists, but no firm conclusions about how to deal with it have been reached. Additionally, almost nobody who has issues with this is willing to invest the time (or funding) into *actually solving the problem*.

Here's a [relevant recent article](http://www.cybertec.at/optimization-issues-cross-column-correlation/). [The optimizer hints wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/OptimizerHintsDiscussion) also covers some correlation issues.

Some mailing list discussions (an extremely non-exhaustive list) include:

- [how to implement selectivity injection in postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/7883.1407968702@sss.pgh.pa.us) - recent
- [Cross column correlation revisited](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/D0F6E707-701C-40C4-9F4B-D7D282AA0187@cybertec.at)
- [How to specify/mock the statistic data of tables in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/52CFB699.2030609@gmail.com)

Answer (score 1):

## Postgres 10

**Update:** Postgres 10 gains *cross-column statistics*, a.k.a. *extended statistics*, a.k.a. *correlated statistics*.

When searching/sorting/grouping on columns that are kinda-sorta related, such as ZipCode and City, tell Postgres to study the data for greater efficiency by the planner.

```sql
CREATE STATISTICS zip_stats_ ( dependencies )
ON zip_ , city_
FROM zipcode_ ;
```

[Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is all about eliminating [functional dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency) between values in a row. But sometimes they remain because of de-normalization, either intentional for performance or unwittingly. And sometimes we have partial dependency such as ZipCode and City. In such cases, if you use these correlated values when searching, sorting, or grouping, first generate cross-column statistics with the [`CREATE STATISTICS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createstatistics.html) command.

## Syntax

Syntax is simple.

Currently two types of statistics, either `dependencies` for an analysis calculation of functional dependency where 1.0 means a direct correlation, and `ndistinct` for an n-distinct analysis of distinct pairs of values. Omitting the types means you want all possible types, which could possibly be more than these two in the future.

```sql
CREATE STATISTICS [ IF NOT EXISTS ] NAME 
[ type = `dependencies` or `ndistinct` or omit for all types ]
ON col_x , col_y , …
FROM tbl ;

ALTER STATISTICS NAME OWNER TO …
ALTER STATISTICS NAME RENAME TO …
ALTER STATISTICS NAME SET SCHEMA …

DROP STATISTICS [ IF EXISTS ] name
```

## Further reading

- [PG Phriday: Crazy Correlated Column Crusade](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/pg-phriday-crazy-correlated-column-crusade/) by Shaun Thomas, 2017-07
- [*Cross Columns Stats*](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Cross_Columns_Stats) Postgres wiki
- Manual, [Chapter 14.2 Statistics Used by the Planner](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/planner-stats.html#planner-stats-extended)
- Manual, [Chapter 68 How the Planner Uses Statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/planner-stats-details.html)
- Wikipedia: [Functional dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency)